# useState is not updating immediately in react

Tags: reactjs

```
//state for time
let [time,setTime] = useState("11:15")

//setTime when change occurs in input

let TimeChange = (t) =>{
        console.log('recieved time is:', t)
        setTime(t)
        console.log(time,': is set')
    }

//using TimePicker inside return

        <TimePicker 
           onChange={TimeChange}
           value={time}
           />
```

**what am expecting in console is:**

recieved time is 12:00

12:00 is set

**what am getting in the console is:**

recieved time is: 12:00

11:15 : is set (// initial time)

recieved time is: 12:30 (// this is the next input i gave)

12:00 : is set (// first update)

My question is why its not updating first time itself?

Comment: `setTime` is an async fucntion, that is why your console prints the old value of `time`.

Comment: @UtsavPatel useState is not asynchronous but OP is logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)

Comment: @HMR I said `setTime` and not `useState`. Read my comment again.

Comment: @UtsavPatel old value is not logged because setTime (the function from useState) is asynchronous but because OP is logging a stale closure.

Comment: Okay, so just answer this, I am a little bit confused.

Is `setTime` an async function? Yes/No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the state using the useState hook does not immediately reflect and update the state but will trigger a re-render.

Comment: useState is not asynchronous but OP is logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)